# How to dynamically access a class and its methods from an input?

Tags: python

I am creating a python CLI, where user can provide an operation they want to perform, for eg:

```
sum 10 15
```

In my code, I have defined my classes as follows:

```
class Operation:
    # common stuff
    pass

class Sum(Operation):
    identifier = "sum"
    def perform(a, b):
        return a + b

class Difference(Operation):
    identifier = "diff"
    def perform(a, b):
        return a - b
```

Now, in my CLI, if I type `sum 10 15` I want to return the result of `Sum.perform(10, 15)` and similarly if I type `diff 10 15`, I return the result of `Difference.perform(10, 15)`, as `sum` is the identifier of class `Sum` and `diff` is the identifier of class `Difference`.

How do I dynamically access the class and its `perform` method, when I get the input directly from user input?

Comment: Have a look at the `cmd` module in the standard library.

Comment: I am using the `cmd` module to get the string `sum` and `diff` and the arguments `a` and `b`. My question is how do I go from the string `sum` and return the result of `Sum.perform(a, b)`.

Comment: Please show your code. The entire purpose of the `cmd` module is to map an input like `sum 10 15` to a function that takes 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Classes in Python are [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), meaning they can be used as standard objects. In particular we can simply store them in a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    'sum': Sum,
    'diff': Difference,
}
```

and so on. Then when you get the operation name as string from command line you simply do

```
my_dict[op_name].perform(a, b)
```

Note that this is a very basic (and you will soon see problematic, e.g. not all operators accept two arguments) approach to what is known as [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). This is a huge topic, a bit hard but also very interesting. I encourage you to read about it.

**// EDIT:** If you want to keep identifier on the class, then you can apply a simple class decorator:

```py
my_dict = {}

def autoregister(cls):
    # It would be good idea to check whether we
    # overwrite an entry here, to avoid errors.
    my_dict[cls.identifier] = cls
    return cls

@autoregister
class Sum(Operation):
    identifier = "sum"
    def perform(a, b):
        return a + b

print(my_dict)
```

You have to remember though to import all classes before you use `my_dict`. In my opinion an explicit dict is easier to maintain.

Comment: In this approach, I'd have to maintain a dictionary mapping the identifier to the class. However, I'm looking for a scalable approach, that does not require me to maintain a separate dictionary. Is it possible via the base Operation class, or by defining a metaclass?

Comment: First of all, you won't have millions of operators, more like few tens at most. So you don't have to worry about scalability. Secondly, sure, you can keep the operator name on the class and autoregister them into some shared dict via class decorator. I'm not sure if it is worth it though. Anyway, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. this seems to solve my issue.

Comment: `my_dict` isn't a class, it's an *instance* of the `dict` class, so your initial statement is irrelevant (and somewhat misleading because generally classes *themselves* aren't used to store data — their instances might).

Comment: @martineau where exactly did I say that `my_dict` is a class? The initial statement refers to OP's classes, I explicitly say that they can be stored in a dict. I don't see anything misleading in my answer.

Comment: @martineau and generally classes can (and it seems that's OP's case) be used to store data. Whether this is a good design is a different question.

Comment: Classes themselves are generally **not** used to store data, although *instances* of the often are. I think it's important to make the distinction clear since classes are "[first-class-citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)" in Python (unlike many other languages).

Comment: @martineau do we talk about other languages here? I don't see how your "important distinction" is relevant in the context. In Python classes can and are used to store data. Btw I already linked the wiki for first-class citizens in my answer. I have a feeling that you didn't read my answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment, I think you need to interpret the input. The way I would go about this is splitting the input by spaces (based on your example), and then checking that list. For example:

```py
# This is the place you called the input:
input_unsplit = input("Enter your command and args")
input_list = input_unsplit.split(" ")

# Check the first word to see what function we're calling
if("sum") in input_list[0].lower():
    result = Sum.perform(input_list[1], input_list[2])
    print(result)
# this logic can be applied to other functions as well.
```

This is a simple solution that could be hard to scale.

=== EDITED ===

I have more to add.

If used correctly, dir() can make a list of defined classes up to a certain point in the code. I wrote a calculator for my precal class, and in it I chose to use dir after defining all the math classes, and then if the name met certain conditions (i.e not **main**), it would be appended to a list of valid args to pass. You can modify your classes to include some kind of operator name property:

```
def class Addition:
    self.op_name = "sum"
```

and then perform to take in an array:

```
    def perform(numbers):
        return numbers[0] + numbers [1]
```

To solve many of your scalability issues. Then, after declaring your classes, use dir() in a for loop to append to that valid array, like so:

```
valid_names = []
defined_names = dir()
for name in defined_names:
    if '_' not in name:
        if name not in ("sys","argparse","<any other imported module/defined var>"):
            valid_names.append(name)
```

Note that making this step work for you is all in the placement in the script. it's a bit tedious, but works flawlessly if handled correctly (in my experience).

Then, you can use eval (safe in this context) to call the method you want:

```
# get input here

for name in defined_names:
    if eval(name).op_name == input_list[0].lower():
        eval(name).perform(input_list)
```

This should be a fairly easy-to-scale solution. Just watch that you keep the dir check up to date, and everything else just... works.

Comment: Yes this would be a hard to scale because I'd want to add multiple other Operations as well, as the need arises. The Sum and Difference are just used as an example.

Comment: Does this fit the original issue a little better? All you have to maintain is the dir() check, and then just write the classes.